# mail function is not working in localhost server

Tags: php, email, localhost

I am on my localhost server. I am using this code below, but I never received the email.

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: Have you configured SMTP to send e-mail via your ISP's mail servers?

Comment: I am using XAMMP, how do you actually do that?

Comment: http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

Comment: Mail function not working on local machine

Answer (score 5):

I know its kinda late...

check if your localhost is configured to send email

On ubuntu terminal 
try executing following command

```
# apt-get install sendmail
```

Comment: This question/answer are almost 10 years old however I just want to note how this just saved me days of confusion wondering why I couldn't send out email on my brand new server which didn't show any errors. Very quick easy fix, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the mailserver is configured correctly in the php.ini file.

comment out these lines like this in php.ini file and restart the Apache server.

```
/*[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25
*/

/*; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
*/
```

Comment: how do you exactly do that?

Comment: http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Comment: I came across with this website, but what do they actually mean by "change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP" This line SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np is where I am getting confuse

Comment: Your ISP should be able to tell you the address of their SMTP. Or, if you have a Gmail account, you can use it: http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

Comment: He tries to use the localhost mailserver of xmpp.