# php mail cannot be sent

Tags: php, email

Im using a mailing form but the mail cannot be sent to gmail inbox !!

here is the code i'm using:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $email   = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];       

    $emailTo = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Sujet:  '.$name;

    $body = "Full Name: $name \n\n  Message: $message \n\n Sent by : $email";
    $headers = 'De: ' .' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";

    if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers)){  
         echo   "Success";

    }else{  
          echo "Error";

    }
}
```

?>

Comment: are you working on `localhost`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14802606/725306, http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/, see this [answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4595838/725306)

Comment: what is $_POST['send'] ?? is it a submit button and if so then it won't work because submit button will never gonna set.

Comment: @user3091574: you are wrong about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code:

```
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_to = "example@email.com";
$email_subject = "Email for: ".$name;

$headers = $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
       'BCC: '.$email_to_bcc."\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
       "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
       "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";

if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "Mail sent";
}
```

Of course your server has to be able to send emails through PHP mail function. Best to set up sending mails through SMTP: Use this script: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer
Easy to set up and works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send emails from localhost directly, you need to install a Mail Transport Agent (MTA), or if you like, a SMTP service.

IIS provides one. You can otherwise find some others [on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+mta).

You can also change your `php.ini` [mail settings](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php). This won't use `localhost` per say to send emails, but a relay host that will allow you to send emails from a PHP script.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595838/725306)