# Not able to send mail using mail function in php

Tags: php

would anyone be able to help me with my question..I am not able to send mail using mail() in php..Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST["from"])) {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    mail("test@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
}
```

while i am running this program in localhost,output showing as "Thank you for sending us feedback" , but not getting  any mail in test@example.com.

Comment: mail() function will not work in your localhost without setup of SMTP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802606/mail-function-is-not-working-in-localhost-server

??

Comment: have you configure the smtp server on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your php.ini cofiguration file and add the mail server config:

```
SMTP = server ; mail server 
smtp_port = 25 ; port
sendmail_from = your@email.com ;
```

Or

Use PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer to send via gmail, yahoo or any external mail server.

Comment: i got it using php mailer..Thanks